# trying a simple show/hide slider for displaying seperate divs, unable to map it to slider.value to an array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have been learning javascript myself from w3school and an opportunity to try some skills I learned arose when I was tackled with a problem of showing different venues at my work according to selected capacity so I decided to make a slider and thought I could map slider.value to an array variable but I have tried that and it doesn't work.

please guide how to approach this, I am really a Lvl 1 so I am sure I am making a really stupid mistake somewhere,
Thanks a lot for you time.

here is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #1A77B9;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Round Range Slider</h1>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="10" max="500" value="20"step ='10' class="slider" id="myRange" onchange ="myfunction()">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>


<script>

var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
var smallCap = [10, 20, 30 , 40, 50];
var Capacity;

function myfunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (slider.value === "50" ) {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Sunny, the code seems to work fine (when you are at 50, it displays a div). What is the array you want to map it to? It is not clear from the description.

Comment: Hi I am sorry I am new to this community and also the coding world so I was not able to list out my question properly.
I meant at 50 it works fine but if I want an array to map to a div

for example, if I create div3 div4 div5
and I want to map an array of 
[30, 40, 50, 60] to div3
[40, 50, 60, 70] to div 4
[80, 90, 100] to div 5

and when the slider reaches any of the value in these arrays they display the div I want to.
Is there a solution to that? I see an answer below and I works fine but I am also still curious is I could use arrays here or not, for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will map the slider to the smallCap array.  I don't know of a way to alter the range after it has been processed by the browser, so this solution creates the slider in the JavaScript code based on values in smallCap and assumes the smallCap values are in ascending order.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #1A77B9;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Round Range Slider</h1>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <!-- input will go here -->
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>

<div class='venue' data-capacity=10>
Venue A has capacity of 10
</div>

<div class='venue' data-capacity=20>
Venue C has capacity of 20
</div>

<div class='venue' data-capacity=30>
Venue Q has capacity of 30
</div>


<script>
    var smallCap = [10, 20, 30 , 40, 50];
    var Capacity;

    var inputTemplate = '<input id="myRange" class="slider" type="range" min={min} max={max} value={value} step=10>'
    inputTemplate = inputTemplate.replace("{min}",smallCap[0]).replace("{max}",smallCap[smallCap.length-1]).replace("{value}",smallCap[0]);
    $('.slidecontainer').prepend(inputTemplate);

    var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
    var output = document.getElementById("demo");

    output.innerHTML = slider.value;
    slider.oninput = function() {
        myfunction(this.value);
    }


    function myfunction(value) {
        output.innerHTML = value;

        document.querySelectorAll('.venue').forEach(item => { item.style.display = 'none'; })

        var element = document.querySelector('.venue[data-capacity="' + value + '"]');
        if (element) {
            element.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

    myfunction(smallCap[0]);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, 
This works perfectly fine! amazing, Thanks a lot, Steve.
although its a different logic and I am trying to understand it ( I am real Noob atm)
Hope you have a great day ahead.